# Change the explorer view of specific folder to large icons using VBA?

Tags: windows, vba, script

is it possible to change the explorer view of `specific folder` `C:\` to **large icons** using VBA ?
I have used this program `RegistryChangesView` to capture changes to windows registry , and I got this data:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU\0\0]
"MRUListEx"=hex(3):00,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,FF,FF,FF,FF
```

I applied later but it has no effect at all (Folder view still list).
I think it can be done by Windows API (I am not familiar with it).
In advance,any help are welcome.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbM5n.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `BagMRU` key indexes saved views, associating a fully-qualified path with a numbered property bag, with the view settings saved in a subkey of the adjacent `Bags` key.

[image: BagMRU key]

[image]

But the numbering/nnaming of the keys is not fixed, but rather dependent on when a folder is first viewed. If a user hasn't viewd the folder in **Explorer**, there won't be a bag. In short, this is not the way to attempt this.

---

---

To manipulate the saved view for a folder, the folder must be open in **Explorer** to access and modify the view using the various com objects available via [`shell.application`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shell). In **PowerShell**, create an instance using:

`$Shell = New-Object -ComObject shell.application`

Use the [`Windows`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shell-windows) method to retrieve open **Explorer** windows. An **EXplorer** window has the following properties:

```
Application          : System.__ComObject
Parent               : System.__ComObject
Container            : 
Document             : System.__ComObject
TopLevelContainer    : True
Type                 : 
Left                 : 0
Top                  : 0
Width                : 1462
Height               : 625
LocationName         : Windows (C:)
LocationURL          : file:///C:/
Busy                 : False
Name                 : File Explorer
HWND                 : 78776658
FullName             : C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe
Path                 : C:\WINDOWS\
Visible              : True
StatusBar            : False
StatusText           : 
ToolBar              : 1
MenuBar              : False
FullScreen           : False
ReadyState           : 4
Offline              : False
Silent               : False
RegisterAsBrowser    : False
RegisterAsDropTarget : True
TheaterMode          : False
AddressBar           : True
Resizable            : True
```

The `Document` property is itself a com object. It's through this object that we can `get`/`set` cetain aspects of the folder view.

```
Application     : System.__ComObject
Parent          : 
Folder          : System.__ComObject
FocusedItem     : System.__ComObject
Script          : 
ViewOptions     : 139
CurrentViewMode : 8
GroupBy         : System.Null
FolderFlags     : 1090519041
SortColumns     : prop:System.ItemNameDisplay;
IconSize        : 32
```

`CurrentVIewMode` and `IconSize` are the values to modify. Use values from the `Mode` column of this table:

```
Name        LVM Mode Vid                                    IconSize
----        --- ---- ---                                    --------
Details     1   4    {137E7700-3573-11CF-AE69-08002B2E1262} 16
Tiles       2   6    {65F125E5-7BE1-4810-BA9D-D271C8432CE3} 48
SmIcons     3   1    {089000C0-3573-11CF-AE69-08002B2E1262} 16..31
Icons(M-XL) 3   1    {0057D0E0-3573-11CF-AE69-08002B2E1262} 33..256
List        4   3    {0E1FA5E0-3573-11CF-AE69-08002B2E1262} 16
Content     5   8    {30C2C434-0889-4C8D-985D-A9F71830B0A9} 32
```

Here's some sample code:

```
$Shell    = New-Object -ComObject shell.application

Function WaitFor-NewWindow ( $CurrentCount )
{
    Do { Sleep -m 50 } Until ( $Shell.Windows().Count -gt $CurrentCount )
}

Function Get-TargetWindow ( $Path )
{
    $OpenWindows = @( $Shell.Windows() )
    If ( $TargetWindow = $OpenWindows | ? { $_.Document.Folder.Self.Path -like $Path } )
    {
        $TargetWindow
    }
    Else
    {
        $Shell.Open( $Target )
        WaitFor-NewWindow $OpenWindows.Count
        @( $Shell.Windows() ) | ? HWND -notIn $OpenWindows.HWND
    }
}

$Target       = 'C:\'
$TargetWindow =  Get-TargetWindow $Target

$TargetWindow.Document.CurrentViewMode = 1
$TargetWindow.Document.IconSize        = 96
$TargetWindow.Quit()
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort , But is it possible to change by VBA or even script rather than registry

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Your posting of the `BagMRU` led me to assume you were wanting to modify the view via a registry edit. That assumption infuenced the emphasis of my answer on the shortcomings of such a route. I will edit my post with a **PowerShell** example as I've forgetten `vbs`/`vba` syntax. But the view modification is accomplished via the `shell.application` and related com objects, so translation shouldn't be much of an issue.

Comment: I am sorry for late reply as I did not got any notification that you updated your initial answer.

Comment: No worries. Waking up to more points is a nice surprise... :D